# Angular UI Date Plugin: On Select does not work

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I am fighting with the datepicker plugin for AngularJS. I have two goals that I have not reached yet:

1. Performing an action when a date has been clicked (see app.directive
   below).
2. Performing this action not inside the directive declaration, but inside the specific controller: `app.controller('dateCtrl', ...)`

Here comes my code:

**HTML:**

```
<div ng-app="MyApp">

   <div ng-controller="someOtherCtrl"> ... </div>

   <div ng-controller="dateCtrl">

      <p>Pick date:</p>

      <input type="text" ng-model="date" ui-date="dateOptions" ui-date-format="yy-mm-dd" custom-datepicker/>

   </div>

   <div ng-controller="someOtherCtrl"> ... </div>

</div>
```

**My JS:**

```
var app = angular.module('myApp', ['ui.date']);

app.controller('dateCtrl', function($rootScope, $scope) {
        $scope.dateOptions = {
            dateFormat:'DD, d  MM yy',
            minDate: 0,
            maxDate: "+6M"
        };

        /* How can I access the on-select-method of my datepicker here inside this controller? */
});

app.directive("customDatepicker", function () {
    return {
        restrict: "A",
        require: "ngModel",
        link: function (scope, elem, attrs, ngModelCtrl) {
            elem.datepicker({
                onSelect: function (dateText) {
                    ngModelCtrl.$setViewValue(dateText);
                    scope.$apply();
                    /* This alert does not work: */
                    alert('i want this to be triggered, but it does not work');
                }
            });
        }
    }
});
```

When I click a date, the alert is not triggered. Why? How do I need to adjust my code?

And what do I need to do in order to trigger this select action inside my app.controller declaration?

Comment: Can you create a plunker or fiddle for this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is my code for datepicker for angularjs, hope this will works for you.
HTML

```
<div ng-app="myApp">
  <div ng-controller="dateCtrl">

    <label>Date : </label>
    <input ng-model="date" ui-date>
    <hr>
      <h1>  {{date | date: 'dd/MM/yyyy'}}</h1>
  </div>
</div>
```

Js Code

```
var myApp = angular.module('myApp', []);

myApp.directive('uiDate', function() {
    return {
      require: '?ngModel',
      link: function (scope, elem, attrs, ngModelCtrl) {
            elem.datepicker({
                onSelect: function (dateText) {
                    ngModelCtrl.$setViewValue(dateText);
                    scope.$apply();
                    /* This alert does not work: */
                    alert('i want this to be triggered, but it does not work');
                }
            });
        }
    };
  });

myApp.controller('dateCtrl', function($rootScope, $scope) {
        $scope.dateOptions = {
            dateFormat:'DD, d  MM yy',
            minDate: 0,
            maxDate: "+6M"
        };

        /* How can I access the on-select-method of my datepicker here inside this controller? */
});
```

and here is working jsFiddle [Link](http://jsfiddle.net/Vd8H2/204/)